# Best practice to force the browser to only render user visible elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A particular page on our site loads with 1000s of divs each about 1000px x ~1500px(A printable page), each div displays additional elements/basic table/etc but can vary in height.

Render time can be several minutes depending on PC performance.

Using tools like [webix](http://webix.com/blog/webix-grid-1-000-000-rows-and-more/) which can load millions of rows proves the render process is taking up most of the loading time, but doesn't work well for non-tabular data.

Using Angular JS to create [infinite scroll](http://twofuckingdevelopers.com/2014/11/angularjs-virtual-list-directive-tutorial/) lists is possible. But this also doesn't work well with varying height elements.

All solutions I have found so far loose the browsers find feature, which our users commonly use, thus we will probably have to develop our own search tool.

Yes we could add pagination, or some sort of way of breaking down the data, but users still need to review all the data regardless of how it's broken down.

The same data (10,000 pages 30mb) once exported to PDF loads in < than 1 second.

I think the best solution will be the combination of a few different ideas.

Comment: You can load template dynamically on particular height from the top and continue doing that infinitely.

Comment: True, however eventually the DOM fills up so much and the page becomes very slow to respond to user input.

Comment: you can try to implement lazyloading something like facebook does on it pages which loads only when you scroll down enough.

Comment: When why not loading the templates dynamically and removing the previous DOM when the user scrolls?

Comment: @warl0ck That is the "infinite scroll" technique the OP mentions, which messes with the browser's Find feature.

Comment: Having that much data in a page is frankly ridiculous. It's far too much for any user to process. Use any combination of paging, filtering, lazy loading and searching.

Comment: I agree it's completely ridiculous hence why we are looking for a better solution, lazy loading/infinite scrolling is a great way to load more data, hidding elements as the users scrolls will help, but the user travels up and down the page checking different values, makes this complicated